# how i can change my time frame in my code pine script

Tags: pine-script

how i can change my time frame to 1min or 1day or 1week
in `_t2 = int(time + change(time))`:

```
f_hline(_price, _color, _style, _width) =>
    _t2 = int(time + change(time))
    var line _line = line.new(x1 = time, y1 = _price, x2 = _t2, y2 = _price, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = _color, style = _style, width = _width, extend = extend.both)
    line.set_xy1(_line, x = time, y = _price)
    line.set_xy2(_line, x = _t2, y = _price)

f_hline(bs, color.red, line.style_dashed, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test this. Hard to say without context if it will do what you need:

```
i_tf = input("M", type = input.resolution)
f_hline(_price, _color, _style, _width, _tf) =>
    _t2 = int(time + change(time(_tf)))
    var line _line = line.new(x1 = time, y1 = _price, x2 = _t2, y2 = _price, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = _color, style = _style, width = _width, extend = extend.both)
    line.set_xy1(_line, x = time, y = _price)
    line.set_xy2(_line, x = _t2, y = _price)
f_hline(bs, color.red, line.style_dashed, 1, i_tf)
```